# Googlebot requesting for same page within short period

Tags: web-crawler, googlebot

I was analysing week over week pages that GoogleBot is requesting for crawling. I can see that GoogleBot is requesting the same page more than 1500 times on a single day. This page is my login page which is basically present on all the pages of my website as part of the website template.

I am concerned about the bandwidth wastage for such repeated crawling.
I have other URLs also which are again present on each page and are being crawled more than 300 times every day of the week. I have verified that it is an actual GoogleBot.
Is this behaviour normal?
Is this related to the presence of the page on many other pages?

Comment: It seems normal to me. If you're unhappy with it, you can limit crawl rate from `Google Webmasters` from the settings. They advise you though not to do it unless google is making your server slow. Here is their message: `Don't limit crawl rate unless Google is slowing down your server.`

Comment: Those high # of requests were because of the redirects from other pages for login.
I see that some search result pages and product detail pages are being requested 50 times in a week with some days of 13-15 requests for that page.On the other hand there are other search result pages and product detail pages which get requested only 1-2 times a week.
It is something related to more pages linking to these pages and bots comes across them more frequently? or bots affinity to these pages for having better SERP/page value.